# AzureDevOps - Cache Task in Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to use the Cache task inside the AzureDevops release pipeline but I'm getting the following error: "Unable to find pipeline caching scopes."

The full log is:

```
2019-12-04T02:52:29.7320092Z ##[section]Starting: Cache Maven local repo
2019-12-04T02:52:29.7323359Z ==============================================================================
2019-12-04T02:52:29.7324096Z Task         : Cache
2019-12-04T02:52:29.7324205Z Description  : Cache files between runs
2019-12-04T02:52:29.7324288Z Version      : 2.0.0
2019-12-04T02:52:29.7324386Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2019-12-04T02:52:29.7324476Z Help         : https://aka.ms/pipeline-caching-docs
2019-12-04T02:52:29.7324596Z ==============================================================================
2019-12-04T02:52:30.1883169Z Resolving key:
2019-12-04T02:52:30.2148089Z  - maven      [string]
2019-12-04T02:52:30.2157501Z  - "Linux"    [string]
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3775363Z  - **/pom.xml [file pattern; matches: 1]
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3776471Z    - /home/vsts/work/r1/a/_GHQ_ABI_Salesforce_OneApp/AutomationTestsPrj/... --> 14132C0725424D58200724C825592A7666659E231F87619340789DA110453697
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3840201Z Resolved to: maven|"Linux"|eoJcSbaPKzXrAAmPNfX9NFnxcoydrNu9yrhaLikHrF8=
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3891079Z Resolving restore key:
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3891618Z  - maven   [string]
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3892061Z  - "Linux" [string]
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3892473Z Resolved to: maven|"Linux"|**
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3892596Z Resolving restore key:
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3892858Z  - maven [string]
2019-12-04T02:52:30.3892979Z Resolved to: maven|**
2019-12-04T02:52:31.7549257Z Information, ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender will correlate events with X-TFS-Session 6a8d4cb9-7af8-4915-8dcc-46b9ded1e10b
2019-12-04T02:52:32.0675474Z Information, Getting a pipeline cache artifact with one of the following fingerprints:
2019-12-04T02:52:32.0676246Z Information, Fingerprint: `maven|"Linux"|eoJcSbaPKzXrAAmPNfX9NFnxcoydrNu9yrhaLikHrF8=`
2019-12-04T02:52:32.0676528Z Information, Fingerprint: `maven|"Linux"|**`
2019-12-04T02:52:32.0676755Z Information, Fingerprint: `maven|**`
2019-12-04T02:52:34.2400712Z Information, ApplicationInsightsTelemetrySender correlated 2 events with X-TFS-Session 6a8d4cb9-7af8-4915-8dcc-46b9ded1e10b
2019-12-04T02:52:34.2485748Z ##[error]Unable to find pipeline caching scopes.
2019-12-04T02:52:34.2528126Z ##[section]Finishing: Cache Maven local repo
```

And my configuration is:
[image: Cache Configuration]

Oh, the variables are created and this task is before the task that I execute the Maven:
[Cache Task order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2kde.png)

So, anybody got an idea of where I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know applying this `Cache` step before your Maven execution is very convenient for pipeline, such as reducing the whole execution time. Just, unfortunately, until now, we haven't provide this `Cache` task supported in **Release pipeline**:

[image: Release pipeline message]

[Pipeline caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/caching/?view=azure-devops)

---

**Work around:**

As I mentioned above, `Cache` task is very convenient because it can help reduce the time waste in file caching.

So, suggest you apply your release pipeline into **Multi-stage YAML** format. Though it is running a release phase, but its compile logic is following build.

Check this doc to convert your pipeline: [YAML schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema).

Comment: Hey guys, thank you for your answers... that was what I was thinking...

Comment: hello guys, it's been 4 years since this issue discussed here. Looks like caching scopes are still not included in release pipeline. Please could anybody suggest on any work around because Multi-stage YAML can no longer be helpful.